# Angular4 - Http error returned is a string instead of an object

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

I'm doing an `Http` request in `Angular 4` using its builtin `HttpClient` class. Everything works well, but there is a small problem with the error variable returned.

When I `post` the wrong username/password combination to login the user, the error object returned contains an `error` key for which the value is expected to be an `Object` but I'm getting a `string` instead. Please see below the text between ** in the object to understand what's the issue:

```
{**error: "{"non_field_errors":["Unable to login with provided credentials."]}"**, headers: Object, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "http://mymedicine.loc/api/auth/login/", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://project.loc/api/auth/login/: 400 Bad Request"}
```

What might cause this kind of problem? I need to have an object there just so I can let the user know what went wrong during the authentication.
I need to precise that the authentication works well when the correct credentials are provided and that I have activated `CORS` on the webserver I'm sending the `HTTP` request to.

Below is a short piece of code extracted which does the `POST` http request:

```js
interface ErrorMessage {
    username: string[1];
    password: string[1];
    non_field_errors: string[1];
}

interface ErrorResponse {
    error: ErrorMessage;
}

// get token from the server
this.http.post<TokenResponse>('http://myproject.loc/api/auth/login/', body).subscribe(
    (res: TokenResponse) => {
        // login with token
        this.auth.login(res.auth_token);

        // redirect
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/url');
    },
    (err: ErrorResponse) => {
        let error = err.error;
        console.dir(err);
    }
);
```

Comment: the json on the error object is formatted as a string, not an object.  Do you control the server? If so, fix it by getting rid of the quotes around your error object. if not, parse the response with JSON.parse

Comment: Have a look at e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18682

Comment: @bryan60 Yes I have control on the data returned by the server, but I don't think the issue is coming from there because the response returned by `curl` on the command line is fine (i.e. a json object)

Comment: you can create an interceptor to make all error JSON.parse and then throw it again, to the caller

Comment: I'm looking at a json formatted string in your sample, it's wrong in the sample or on the server. Objects aren't surrounded in quotes, just brackets. Everytime I use curl, it outputs the body of my response unparsed.  I don't know if you have some curl json parsing plugin that I dont, but I would never think to use curl to debug json.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It seems like a recent problem. With an exact same project which was generated with an older version of `angular-cli` I don't have this problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is a sample of the error returned by `curl` on the CLI: `{"non_field_errors":["Unable to login with provided credentials."]}`. You can see that it's not a string as in the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error seems to have been fixed by recent versions of `Angular` and `Angular-cli` according to [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18682), and I don't have it with `Angular 4.4.6`.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting Content-Type to json in the headers of your post request for the server

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');   

return this.http.post<TokenResponse>('/api/auth/login/', body, {headers: headers})
           .map(res => {
                 return {token: res.auth_token};
           }).catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                 if (err.error) {
                     console.log(err.error);
                 }
                 return _throw(err);
        });
```

Comment: Setting the content-type doesn't solve this issue (in fact the content-type is already in `json` event without explicitely setting it).